# Objective C: Protocol (delegate) and multiple arguments?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm new to Objective C (iOS) and I'm having a hard time figuring out this cryptic language.

I have no problem making a protocol (delegate) with one argument...

*Person.h:*

```
protocol PersonDetailsDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void) GetName:(NSString *) name;
@end
```

*Person.m:*

```
- (void) FireUpDelegate {
    [self.delegate GetName: @"Michael"];
}
```

*FirstViewController.m:*

```
- (void) GetName: (NSString *) name {
    NSLog(@"%@", name);    
}
```

**But I can't figure out using two arguments....**

*Person.h:*

```
@protocol PersonDetailsDelegate <NSObject>
@required
-(void) GetName:(NSString *) name; getAge:(int *) age;
@end
```

*Person.m:*

```
- (void) FireUpDelegate {
    [self.delegate GetName: @"Michael"; getAge: 49];
}
```

*FirstViewController.m:*

```
- (void) GetName: (NSString *) name getAge: (int) age {
    NSLog(@"%@ .. %i", name, age);    
}
```

I get a quite some errors - any idea where it goes wrong?

Thanks a million!!

Mojo

Comment: If you get quite some errors, then, well _read_ them and try to find out what they mean. And if you get errors, and want to ask a question, it is nice if you _copy and paste_ at least the first few of them here and tell _where_ they happen. That makes answering such a question a lot easier.

Comment: Methods should start with lower case letters and you should not name a method starting with `get` outside of very rare circumstances (which this isn't one of).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one `;` too many (after `name`). It should be:

```
-(void) GetName:(NSString *) name getAge:(int) age;
```

The `;` makes the compiler think the declaration of the method is finished, and that the method name is `GetName:`. If you remove the `;`, it is properly parsed as `GetName:getAge:`.

EDIT: changed `(int *)` to `(int)`.

Comment: Thanks a million! I'm having a hard time figuring out the logic behind Objective C. Thanks again! :)

Comment: IME, Objective-C is an acquired taste, i.e. it needs some getting used to, like coffee or beer (no one likes them for the first time <g>), but once you start to know it, it gets addictive.

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove the semicolon (`;`) after `name`.
2. Remove the star (`*`) in `(int *)age`. It can also raise an error.

Your code should look like this:

```
-(void) GetName:(NSString *) name getAge:(int) age;
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, remove the semicolons in GetName method